# Remove a character at an index position in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Basically what the question says. How can I delete a character at a given index position in a string? The String class doesn't seem to have any methods to do this.

If I have a string "HELLO" I want the output to be this

```
["ELLO", "HLLO", "HELO", "HELO", "HELL"]
```

I do that using

```
d = Array.new(c.length){|i| c.slice(0, i)+c.slice(i+1, c.length)}
```

I dont know if using slice! will work here, because it will modify the original string, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat m.rb
class String
  def maulin! n
    slice! n
    self
  end
  def maulin n
    dup.maulin! n
  end
end
$ irb
>> require 'm'
=> true
>> s = 'hello'
=> "hello"
>> s.maulin(2)
=> "helo"
>> s
=> "hello"
>> s.maulin!(1)
=> "hllo"
>> s
=> "hllo"
```

Comment: Is there any big difference between `self.class.new(self).maulin! n` and `self.dup.maulin! n`?

Answer (score 14):

Won't Str.slice! do it? From ruby-doc.org:

> str.slice!(fixnum) => fixnum or nil [...]
>
> ```
>  Deletes the specified portion from str, and returns the portion deleted.
> ```

Comment: it returns the ascii value of the character. I want whats left of the string to be returned.

Comment: Then `str.slice!(fixnum); str`.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Ruby 1.8, you can use delete_at (mixed in from Enumerable), otherwise in 1.9 you can use slice!.

Example:

```
mystring = "hello"
mystring.slice!(1)  # mystring is now "hllo"
# now do something with mystring
```

Comment: `delete_at` isn't part of `Enumerable`. It is just part of `Array`. So `delete_at` isn't available in `String`.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid needing to monkey patch `String` you can make use of `tap`:

```
"abc".tap {|s| s.slice!(2) }
=> "ab"
```

If you need to leave your original string unaltered, make use of `dup`, eg. `abc.dup.tap`.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this

```
c.slice(0, i)+c.slice(i+1, c.length)
```

Where c is the string and i is the index position I want to delete. Is there a better way?

Comment: slice! will modify the string in place. So just call slice! on your string with the index of the char you want deleted. Don't use the return value.

Comment: Sure, you can get the exact same non-destructive behavior as slice by just using the indexes in the bracket syntax: c[0, i] + c[i+1, c.length]